# I need to remove white spaces from console input that forms a list

Tags: c#, .net-core

Ok so this is one of my exercises that I can't figure out.

The input is : 1 2 3 |4 5 6 |  7  8

What i need to print out is : 7 8 4 5 6 1 2 3

What i pretty much get is : 1 2 3 4 5 6   7  8

I need you guys to help me find out what the problem may be

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp41
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string tokens = Console.ReadLine();
            List<string> list = tokens.Split('|').ToList();
            List<string> listTwo = new List<string>(list.Count);

            foreach (var token in list)
            {
                token.Split(" ");
                listTwo.Add(token);
            }

            foreach (var token in listTwo)
            {
                listTwo.Remove(" ");
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < listTwo.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(listTwo[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You just need to split your input by `|`, then inside reverse-for loop print your `string` array content. Or in one line `string result = string.Join(" ", input.Split('|').Select(s => s.Trim()).Reverse());`

Comment: Your expected result does not match with your requirement.

Comment: @SeM that should have been an answer IMO

Comment: `token.Split(" ");` returns something, you need to catch that.

Answer (score 2):

Your "exercise" solution is one line to me:

```
string input = "1 2 3 |4 5 6 | 7 8";
string result = string.Join(" ", input.Split('|').Select(s => s.Trim()).Reverse());
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

but for exercise purposes, it would be better if you do it step by step, to understand more whats going on (for example):

```
//Split your string to string[] by given separator
string[] splitedString = input.Split('|');

//create new array to store your result values
string[] resultArray = new string[splitedString.Length];

//loop backwards through your array and store your values into new array (resultArray)
for (int i = splitedString.Length - 1, j = 0; i >= 0; i--, j++)
{
    resultArray[j] = splitedString[i].Trim();
}

//Iterate through new array and construct new string from existing values, 
//method Trim() is removing leading and trailing whitespaces
string result = string.Empty;
foreach (string item in resultArray)
{
    result += item + " ";
}

Console.WriteLine(result.Trim());
```

References: [MSDN String.Trim()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3(v=vs.110).aspx), [DotNetPerls C# Trim Strings](https://www.dotnetperls.com/trim)

Answer (score 0):

this may help you

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp41
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string tokens = Console.ReadLine();
            List<string> list = tokens.Split('|').ToList();
            List<string> listTwo = new List<string>(list.Count);

            foreach (var token in list)
            {
                token.Split(" ");
                listTwo.Add(token);
            }

            foreach (var token in listTwo)
            {
                listTwo.Remove(" ");
            }
         //change this loop like this
            for (int i =listTwo.Count-1 ; i >0 ; i--)
            {
                Console.Write(listTwo[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in last `for`, should be `listTwo.Count - 1`

Comment: see the edited version it will fix your out of range exception

Comment: @primo check my comment, if you try accessing `listTwo[listTwo.Count]` this is where you get an `OutOfRangeException`

Comment: You still need `i>=0` if you want to print `listTwo[0]` though

Comment: Moreover, as for OP, you don't seem to understand that `token.Split(" ");` is quite useless if you don't assign the result of it to anything, so the first `foreach` loop wont do what you think it does. Also, you are using `foreach(var token in listTwo)` but inside this loop you remove something in `listTwo` and don't use `token`, so I don't really understand why you even use a `foreach`

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the simple way of doing

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string tokens = "1 2 3 |4 5 6 | 7 8";
    var list = tokens.Split('|');

    list = list.Reverse().Select(n=> n.Trim().PadRight(n.Length,' ')).ToArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(list[i]);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**WHAT I DID**

1. Reverse the array which you got after splitting your input string. I used inbuilt `Reverse()` function. No need to code your own until compulsory. Advantage of framework and C#.
2. `Select()` is `LINQ` function which helps to select element from any list,array (many more but for basic understanding list and array). (It will iterate to each element though it is not a loop.)
3. `Trmi()` will remove leading and trailing space and then `PadRight()` will add required space to each element in array.

**OUTPUT**

```
7 8 4 5 6 1 2 3
```

Comment: While simple, if OP is a beginner as it seems, he might not understand how `Select`, `Trim` and `PadRight` work, so it could be interesting to explain it a little

Answer (score 0):

- Split your string with '|'.
- Iterate through each element of array in reverse order and use
  [`Trim()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3(v=vs.110).aspx).
- Concatenate string with space to result, I used [`StringBuilder`](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-stringbuilder) to append result, Return full string

---

```
public string GetArrayString(string token)
{
    //Here you split
    string[] arr = token.Split('|');
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    //Use for loop in reverse order, as you want to reverse the string 
    for(int i = arr.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
      //Append result to stringbuilder object with " "
      sb.Append(arr[i].Trim() + " ");
    }
    //Convert string builder object to string and return to the main function
    return sb.ToString().Trim();
}

   public static void Main(string[] args)
   { 
      //Read inputs from user in your case it is 1 2 3 |4 5 6 | 7 8
       string token = Console.ReadLine();
      //Here function will return expected output; note you need to create instance of class otherwise assign GetArrayString method as a static
       Console.WriteLine(GetArrayString(string token));
   }
```

**Output**

```
7 8 4 5 6 1 2 3
```

POC : [DotNetFiddler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cPmZSj)

Answer (score 0):

While everyone is basically giving you a working solution, I will answer that part of your question:

> I need you guys to help me find out what the problem may be

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp41
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string tokens = Console.ReadLine();
            List<string> list = tokens.Split('|').ToList();
            List<string> listTwo = new List<string>(list.Count);

            foreach (var token in list)
            {
                // the following line won't do anything
                // as you don't assign its result to a variable
                token.Split(" ");
                // so you are only adding every token from list in listTwo
                listTwo.Add(token);
            }
            // at this point, the content of list and listTwo are the same

            foreach (var token in listTwo)
            {
                // you are iterating through 'listTwo', and you don't even
                // use 'token', so what's that foreach for?
                // do you really believe 'listTwo' contains that much " "?
                // as a reminder, listTwo = { "1 2 3 ", "4 5 6 ", " 7 8" }
                listTwo.Remove(" ");
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < listTwo.Count; i++)
            {
                // here you just print the original 'tokens' without '|'
                Console.Write(listTwo[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```